# what is a better way to parse python code, for specific pep8 issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pep8, python-re

I am aware, that libraries exist for parsing python code, however, for the sake of learning how they parse errors, I'm creating a script that checks a file for only 6 Pep8 errors just for reference.

This is how my current 6 Pep8 functions look (they append an issue to the issues list, if issue was found)

```py
"""
[S001] Line is longer than 79 characters
[S002] Indentation is not a multiple of four
[S003] Unnecessary semicolon after a statement (note, semicolons are admissible in comments)
[S004] At least two spaces before inline comments required
[S005] TODO found (only in comments; the case does not matter)
[S006] More than two blank lines used before this line (must be output for the first non-empty line)
"""
def S001(self, ln_num: int, line: str):
    if len(line) > 79:
        self.issues.append(f"Line {ln_num}: S001 Too Long")


def S002(self, ln_num: int, line: str):
    indentation_length = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
    if indentation_length % 4 != 0:
        self.issues.append(f"Line {ln_num}: S002 Indentation is not a multiple of four")


def S003(self, ln_num: int, line: str):
    regex1 = re.compile("(.*)((;(\s)*#)|(;$))")
    regex2 = re.compile("#.*;")
    if regex1.search(line) and not regex2.search(line):
        self.issues.append(f"Line {ln_num}: S003 Unnecessary semicolon")


def S004(self, ln_num: int, line: str):
    regex = re.compile("(([^ ]{2})|(\s[^ ])|([^ ]\s))#")
    if regex.search(line):
        self.issues.append(f"Line {ln_num}: S004 At least two spaces before inline comments required")


def S005(self, ln_num: int, line: str):
    regex =  re.compile("#(.*)todo", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if regex.search(line):
        self.issues.append(f"Line {ln_num}: S005 TODO found")


def S006(self, ln_num: int, line: str):
    if self.code[ln_num-4:ln_num-1] == ['', '', ''] and line != "":
        self.issues.append(f"Line {ln_num}: S006 More than two blank lines used before this line")
```

Testcases:

```
""" Test case 1 """
print('What\'s your name?') # reading an input
name = input();
print(f'Hello, {name}');  # here is an obvious comment: this prints greeting with a name


very_big_number = 11_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000
print(very_big_number)



def some_fun():
    print('NO TODO HERE;;')
    pass; # Todo something
""" END """

""" Test Case 2 """
print('hello')
print('hello');
print('hello');;;
print('hello');  # hello
# hello hello hello;
greeting = 'hello;'
print('hello')  # ;
""" END """

""" Test Case 3 """
    print('hello')
    print('hello')  # TODO
    print('hello')  # TODO # TODO
    # todo
    # TODO just do it
    print('todo')
    print('TODO TODO')
    todo()
    todo = 'todo'
""" END """

""" Test Case 4 """
print("hello")


print("bye")



print("check")
""" END """

""" Test Case 5 """
print('hello!')
# just a comment
print('hello!')  #
print('hello!')  # hello

print('hello!') # hello
print('hello!')# hello
""" END """
```

Testcase 1 Expected Output:

```
Line 1: S004 At least two spaces before inline comment required
Line 2: S003 Unnecessary semicolon
Line 3: S001 Too long
Line 3: S003 Unnecessary semicolon
Line 6: S001 Too long
Line 11: S006 More than two blank lines used before this line
Line 13: S003 Unnecessary semicolon
Line 13: S004 At least two spaces before inline comment required
Line 13: S005 TODO found
```

I am aware my code, is not optimal, and doesn't satisfy every edge case, but I want an idea, on how they parse the errors properly. I would like improvements, or better ideas on how to parse for errors, since i personally don't like my answers.

Comment: Maybe start by looking at the code for one of the existing pep8 linters? That might give you a much better idea about how they work.